# Extending VB.net Classes in C#.net

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I am currently exploring the possibility of combining both VB.net and C#.net into the same solution, with a view to stopping writing VB.net code and later down the line, refactoring what's been written into C#. My understanding of the .net framework suggests that I can extend a class of one language using a class of another language, but I simply cannot find a way to make it work.

As a mock-up, I've created a VB.Net console app that looks a lot like this:

```
Namespace CrossLanguage

Module Module1

    Sub Main()

        Console.WriteLine("This is a test")
        Console.ReadLine()

        Dim x As New Test

        x.WriteMeAnAnimal()

    End Sub

End Module

Public Class Test

    Sub WriteMeAnAnimal()

        Console.WriteLine("An animal")
        Console.ReadLine()

    End Sub

End Class

End Namespace
```

This works and there's no real issue with it. I can run up the app and at the first ReadLine, I can submit anything I like and 'An animal' appears. Now, all I've done next is create a new C# project, with one class file. I've added a project reference to point to the VB.net project (which is fine), but I simply cannot get the C# class to see that the VB class exists:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using Test;

namespace CrossLanguage
{
    public class Dog : Test
    {
    }
}
```

The IDE errors on the references to Test, with the whole "could not be found, are you missing..." shenanigans.

Am I missing something?

Comment: You code and idea *should* work, but please post the exact compiler error. Does the `Test` class appear in Class View or the Object Browser windows in the IDE? Also note that C# is case-sensitive, VB.NET is not, so it might be a casing issue. Finally you must make every method in your classes `virtual` (`Overridable` in VB.NET) for you to override them.

Comment: VB has a root namespace for each project and any namespaces declared in files nest within that. C# doesn't have such a concept. So, you probably have a class called `SomeProject.CrossLanguage.Test` - which is in a different namespace to `CrossLanguage.Dog`. So either you need to add a using directive (as the error told you) or adjust your namespaces.

Comment: `using CrossLanguage;`

Comment: using keyword is used to import a namespace.

Comment: Why are you highlighting the differences between the languages? You should be making the process seamless; `CrossLanguage` just draws attention to it.

Answer (score -1):

It sadly seems that this was some quirk of Visual Studio. Having reviewed your comments, I sat down today and opened the solution to try a couple of things and, well, it works without me changing anything.

Thanks for your help regardless.

Ashilta